# Speed up Jsoup for android

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

For my android app I am currently using Jsoup to connect and extract data from 6 websites, I have put these into 6 methods that execute Sequentially:

```
 getAndExtractWebsite1();
 getAndExtractWebsite2();
 getAndExtractWebsite3();
 etc....
```

I would like to know how it would be possible to speed up the process of collecting the data from the websites, its currently around 10secs in total. Can these calls be executed in parallel or how do you manage multiple websites when collecting data.
Any examples would be welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want parallel execution, you should look at multithreading.

One way to do this is with `AsyncTasks`. By default they run sequentially but you can get them to run in parallel by using a different executor. This is described [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask_parallel).

You can also use the basic java async framework. This is described [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html).

Comment: Hi, all of the calls are currently taking place inside of an AsyncTask but sequentially. So to understand before reading your links...would I create a different AsyncTask for each website that I want parsing and then run all of the Tasks in parallel?

Comment: Yes, that's the gist of it. Maybe create one subclass that defines the behaviour (if it's similar) and just pass the url to it, to keep your code cleaner.